# Light chess literature for beginning kids and their parents

Tags: books

I'm looking for book recommendations for kids learning chess and their parents, or for the broad general public intrigued by chess. The idea is to read stories true, or faked, that fire the imagination to promote chess enthusiasm, to educate on chess history and chess culture. Preferably with nice illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

These two books are a good starting point, IMO.

[Chess for Kids from Micheal Basman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/075661807X)  
[How to Beat Your Dad at Chess (Gambit Chess)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983056)

Answer (score 2):

Check the USCF Sales site. They are very pro-kids and parents when it comes to beginning chess literature. You might find something there:

https://www.uscfsales.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=chess+for+kids

Answer (score 2):

[Bobby Fischer Teaches Chess](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553263153) is another good one. It's a book of problems that are to be solved in sequence, with the principles learned earlier used in later problems.  $3.50 (used) from Amazon.

Comment: Used is not a good option: the book is meant to be written in.  Anyway, new was under $10 last I checked.

Answer (score 1):

There's a really nice publication for both parents and kids, [Capakhine](http://capakhine.es/), but it is a Spanish one. As there are many Spanish-speaking users, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

"The Immortal Game: A History of Chess or How 32 Carved Pieces on a Board, Illuminated Our Understanding of War, Art, Science, and the Human Brain" by David Shenk is definitely not for kids, but it is a competent history of chess with special emphasis on its interaction with culture in the broadest sense.